# how to pass parameters up inheritance hierarchy in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a `controller` named `MyController` which has a method named `myMethod`. I call `MyController::myMethod` from an `erb view` from a `link_to` link; I also pass a parameter named `myParam`

I have this in my `ApplicationController`

```
before_action :check_login
```

So calling `MyController::myMethod` will apparently call `ApplicationController::check_login`. Will `myParam` be available in `ApplicationController::check_login?

If not (it does not seem to be available from the debugging I have done so far), is there a way to pass it over? Pls help!

Comment: Why are you calling controller methods from view, that is not how things are supposed to work in Rails.

Comment: I have a `link_to` in a view; when the user clicks it, I need to invoke a controller method. I pass a parameter when I do that as well.

Comment: That being said you can do `before_action :check_login, except: :your_method_name`

Comment: I need `check_login` to be executed for my method also. I have a `create` operation in `CRUD` that needs to be triggered when the user clicks a `link_to`. The `create` operation has to hit a controller method; I need to pass a parameter along as well.

Comment: "I also pass a parameter named myParam" - how exactly do you do this? What does the code look like? When you click on the link, what does your console log show?

Comment: `link_to my_url, :my_param =>  'my_value'`.   This is how I pass the param

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you're passing it the wrong way.

```
= link_to my_url(my_param: 'my_value')
```

then you have access to it in all your controller methods

```
def check_login
  my_value = params.fetch(:my_param, 'some default if you want to')
end
```